# Lentidão no Entity C# ao salvar imagem

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com uma lentidão no sistema que criei em c# usando Entity Framework. No momento em que vou salvar um registro de um anexo, estou compactando o arquivo. Antes verifico se ele é .jpg ou .pdf (únicas extensões aceitas pelo sistema). Os arquivos que estou anexando possuem no máximo 1MB, e ainda assim o sistema apresenta lentidão... Aparece como "Não respondendo" e depois de um certo tempo (20 segundos aproximadamente), persiste. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Já verifiquei a rede (está normal) e a configuração do computador é boa.

Seguem meus códigos do método para salvar e compactar os arquivos.

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidaForm())
        {
            FANEXOMOVIMENTACAO anex = new FANEXOMOVIMENTACAO
            {
                MovimentacaoID = movimentacao.MovimentacaoID,
                AnexoID = txtCodAnexo.Text,
                Descricao = txtDescricao.Text,
                Tipo = "COMUM",
                Nome = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtArquivo.Text),
                Extensao = Path.GetExtension(txtArquivo.Text),
                Arquivo = (Path.GetExtension(txtArquivo.Text) == ".pdf" ? Global.EncriptPDF(txtArquivo.Text) : Global.EncriptFoto(txtArquivo.Text)),
                DataCadastro = DateTime.Now,
                UsuarioCadastro = FormPrincipal.getUsuarioAcesso().LoginUsr
            };

            using (controle = new ControleFAnexoMovimentacao())
            {
                controle.Create(anex);
                controle.SaveAll();
                Global.MsgSucesso("Registro salvo com sucesso.");
                salvo = true;
            }

            if (Global.NovoRegistro() == DialogResult.Yes)
                LimparCampos();
            else
                this.Close();
        }
    }
```

E este é para compactar os arquivos:

```
 public static byte[] EncriptFoto(string img)
    {
        byte[] bytesImagem = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(img, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        bytesImagem = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

        return CompressBytes(bytesImagem);
    }


public static byte[] EncriptPDF(string pdf)
    {
        byte[] arrayDeBytes;

        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(pdf, FileMode.Open))
        {
            arrayDeBytes = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
            stream.Read(arrayDeBytes, 0, arrayDeBytes.Length);
        }

        return CompressBytes(arrayDeBytes);
    }
```

Comment: É SQL-Server? Se sim, verifique os log de expansão dos arquivos de BD e Log. Muitos registros de expansão, podem causar lentidão na gravação, bem como, a escrita dos índices. Esses podem não ser o principal fator, mas podem ser alguns deles.

Comment: Consegue debugar para ver qual é a parte em que ocorre a maior lentidão?

Comment: Essa lentidão está ocorrendo no cliente. Na minha máquina local não está ocorrendo. Vou tentar inserir muitos anexos no banco para ver se consigo reproduzir o ambiente... mas ainda acho que não é esta a causa do problema.

Comment: Acho que descobri o motivo do problema... sobrecarga no Banco de dados. Olhei os relatórios gerados pelo próprio SQL e notei que meu método de compactação não está compactando, apenas convertendo em um array de bytes.